# Android error: package org.apache.tools.ant does not exist

Tags: android, sardine

I'm trying to add com.github.sardine library and build my app with it. 
It fails with the following error

```
Error:(3, 28) error: package org.apache.tools.ant does not exist
```

Solution is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding of the following line to dependencies in build.gradle (Module: app) helps.

```
dependencies {
...
    compile group: 'org.apache.ant', name: 'ant', version: '1.8.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add that to your **build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```